# terraform Resource share

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

I have a terraform template module that looks like this

```
.
├── example
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── policies.tf
├── roles.tf
├── main.tf
├── provider.tf
└── variable.tf
```

inside the main.tf inside example path I have a resource that depends on a resource that is part of me main.tf how can I call resource with  depends_on = [] if they're not part of the same file and path

Comment: Depends on how? Can you provide a [mcve] that shows what you're trying to do? You might be able to achieve this in some ways or you may need to restructure things but it's hard to know without seeing what you're doing exactly beyond a pseudo file structure.

Answer (score 0):

> if they're not part of the same file and path

You can't do this. You have to re-think your architecture and probably change it so that such dependency does not happen.